# Cosmological inflation in LQG/LQC

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation, loop-quantum-gravity

I seek the state-of-the-art report on how cosmological inflation is described by loop quantum cosmology.

I know that LQG/LQC predicts a big bounce to replace the classical big bang singularity of GR. According to the modern cosmology, after the Big Bang the newly-born Universe starts exponentially expanding in size (which is known as cosmological inflation).

General Relativity and Standard Model fields are obviously unable to describe cosmological inflation. A special "inflaton" field driving this process of inflation have been proposed to address the problem, leading to the models of eternal inflation in the Multiverse.

I was wondering how LQC attempts to address the problem. As far as I see, there are three possibilities:

1. Maybe, LQG/LQC has its own mechanism responsible for cosmological inflation (like the repulsive effect of quantum gravity which is responsible for the bounce).
2. Maybe, LQC inflation models also make use of the "inflaton" field.
3. Maybe, something else happens. Like LQC does not need inflation to explain the observed phenomena, or something else which I am not aware of.

P.S. Please don't submit answers like "Loop Gravity / Loop Cosmology is a loosing proposition and is unable to describe anything".